# Java: missing return statement after try-catch

Tags: java

I'm using the code below in a `Triangle` class to allow the user to set the first, second, or third point of a declared `Triangle`.

```
public Point get(String p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    IllegalArgumentException e = new IllegalArgumentException();
    try {
        if (p == "first") { return first; }
        else if (p == "second") { return second; }
        else if (p == "third") { return third; }
        else { throw e; }
    }
    catch (e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

The compiler is telling me:

```
Triangle.java:41: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
```

But I thought the point of the catch statement was to be able to catch an error and return a string describing the error, without having to worry about matching the function's return type.

Comment: You're [comparing strings by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) but that particular error is because the `catch` block doesn't lead to a `return` or a `throw` and this method needs to return a `Point`.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicates. See [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077)

Answer (score 6):

Because you're missing a `return` statement.

The method declares that it returns something, so it *must* return something (or throw an exception).  The compiler can't guarantee that any of the `return` statements in the `try` block will be reached if an exception is thrown before any of them execute.  So the `catch` block also needs to return something (or throw an exception, or return something after the `try/catch` construct entirely).

**Edit:** Looking again, you're also potentially missing a `return` in the `try` block.  (If you don't have one after the entire `try/catch` structure.)  What if none of the conditions in the `if/else` structure are satisfied?  Nothing is returned.  Which is invalid.

Basically, all logical paths must result in a valid exit of the method.  You've missed two such paths.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning anything in your function on several paths.

> But I thought the point of the catch statement was to be able to catch an error and return a string describing the error, without having to worry about matching the function's return type.

That's not at all what a `try-catch` does, and moreover your function is declared to return a `Point` not a `String`.

`try-catch` simply "catches" a `Throwable` (`Error` or `Exception`) and allows you to run some code when it is thrown instead of simply terminating the application with an `Uncaught Exception/Error`.

You need to return some value from your function after the `try-catch` there is no way to return a string, nor is there a language construct in place that behaves like you've explained your understanding of `try-catch`.

Also your code cna't actually throw an `IllegalArgumentException` so your `catch` block will never get called. In this case, it sounds like what you want is instead something like this

```
public Point get(String p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (p == null) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
        if (p.equals("first")) { return first; }
        else if (p.equals("second")) { return second; }
        else if (p.equals("third")) { return third; }
        else { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }
}
```

The code could then be called like so

```
Point p;
try {
    p = get("notFirst");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    //oh no, we gave a bad argument, and the method told us nicely.
}
```

Comment: I don't see him returning a string, I see him returning a named variable of an unknown type, which may very well be a Point

Comment: I agree @Shadow but read the quoted section please. "return a string describing the error without having to worry about matching the function's return type" It sounds a lot more like he wants to `throw` an `Exception` rather than handle one (since none of that code can actually throw an `IllegalArgumentException` anyway.

Comment: Yeah but by "return a string" he is referring to using `System.out.println()` in his `catch` block. Either way +1 for the `throws IllegalArgumentException` on the function

Comment: Ah that would make sense. Well I guess I'll leave this up as is and let him come back with clarifications if possible. Thanks Shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two parts:
1. A `return` statement in try block for else condition
2. Catch block doesn't lead to a `return` statement or a `throw` statement

I don't know if type of first, second, third variables are string or Point, but you should return with Point, because your function is :
public **Point** get(String p) {
...
}

Answer (score -1):

You have three if statements. What happens when the input doesn't satisfy any of those? Your method doesn't have a return statement for that case.